PDF Flickering on render react-pdf
I have a react app with vite using react-pdf. I want to accomplish the same smoothness that for example Chrome's built in pdf renderer has when zooming in from the mousepad. However, when I try to zoom in using react-pdf it flickers a bit. I have tried memoization, not actually using the scale prop for the pdf, and some other quick fixes, but nothing works. Here is the code where I'm rendering the pdf:
import { FC } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";

interface PDFViewerProps {
  pdfUrl: string;
  scale: number;
  rotation: number;
  onLoadSuccess: ({ numPages }: { numPages: number }) => void;
  numPages?: number;
}

const PDFViewer: FC<PDFViewerProps> = ({
  pdfUrl,
  rotation,
  onLoadSuccess,
  numPages,
  scale,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full overflow-auto">
      <Document
        file={pdfUrl}
        onLoadSuccess={onLoadSuccess}
        className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-start flex-col"
      >
        {Array.from({ length: numPages || 0 }, (_, i) => (
          <Page
            key={i + 1}
            pageNumber={i + 1}
            rotate={rotation}
            scale={scale}
          />
        ))}
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PDFViewer;

I know that I haven't implemented a pinch zoom feature here but that is not the tricky part. I want to know how to avoid flickering of the pdf's re-rendering.
I have tried to use some third party libraries for pinch zooming to zoom an outer div and not the actual pdf itself but that was a mess.
